# Argument of type 'readonly X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X'

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I was using a third-party library that has this class:

```
export class Foo {
  field: X[];
  ….
}
```

I was consuming this type in my code:

```
print(foo.field)
```

now with a new version the field definition changed to this

```
export class Foo {
  readonly foo: readonly X[];
  ….
}
```

so my code throws an error:

> Argument of type 'readonly X' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'X'.

here is my function:

```
function print(foo: Foo[]): string {
  return //process foo, return some form of string
}
```

I wonder how to fix that error?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates the issue?  Right now it seems like pseudocode and the error is also paraphrased (`'readonly X'` is unlikely to appear like that; there is no general `readonly` modifier on *types*; although there is shorthand where `readonly X[]` stands for `ReadonlyArray<X>`, but that's specifically arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not mutating the array passed to your function, then you should add `readonly` to it as well:

```
function print(foo: readonly Foo[]): string {
  return //process foo, return some form of string
}
```

Using `readonly type[]` is a way to tell Typescript that an array is expected and that this array will not be modified. Typescript enforces this by exposing only read-only methods on this array and disallow assignment to it:

```
const myArray: readonly string[] = [];
myArray[0] = 's'
// Index signature in type 'readonly string[]' only permits reading.(2542)
myArray.push('a')
// Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly string[]'.(2339)
```

`readonly type[]` is equivalent to `ReadonlyArray<type>` and you can find more explanations in [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#readonly-and-const).

Comment: ok, it does solve the problem, can you explain the mechanics of this or point to the right direction? Is it like the new way of handling all readonly props now in the recent TS?

Comment: I edited my answer to add more details.

Comment: so does that mean that according with TS rules if prop is marked as readonly you had to mark it as read only all the way where you pass it as a param? This is seems like some sort of immutability enforcement to me.

Comment: Correct, once it's `readonly`, it needs to be `readonly` all the way. But it is only a compile-time enforcement, the array is still a normal mutable array at runtime. Also, if you cast the `readonly` array to a mutable array, mutation methods are accessible again (but as most casts, it's a potentially dangerous practice).

Comment: Note that a `readonly` *property* is almost completely different than a `readonly` *array*; readonly properties are mutually assignable with mutable ones (e.g., `{readonly a: number}` and `{a: number}` are mutually assignable) while `readonly` *arrays* are not known to have all of the methods of arrays (specifically the mutating ones like `push()`).